# View the number of entries recorded per day

Tags: posts, post-type

I want to display a chart of the number of articles published from a post_type within a specified time period (e.g. 30 days).
Example :
1/1/2019 (1)
1/2/2019 (15)
1/3/2019 (0)
1/4/2019 (6)
1/5/2019 (0)
1/6/2019 (3)
1/7/2019 (7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is by using custom MySQL query with `WPDB` class.

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
$sql = "SELECT DATE(post_date) AS date, COUNT(ID) AS count 
    FROM {$table} WHERE post_type = 'my_post_type' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY DATE(post_date)";
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Or if you want to prevent SQL injection, you can use prepared statement like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE(post_date) AS date, COUNT(ID) AS count 
    FROM %s WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY DATE(post_date)",
    array(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'posts',
        'my_post_type'
    )
);
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Then you can iterate the `$rows` to show the data.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->date . ' -- ' . $row->count;
}
```

Comment: You’re not preventing any SQL injection in here, because there is no user input in your query used... And you should use ‘$wpdb->posts‘ - there is no point in any concatenation and using prefixes here, there is already value that is calculated and ready to use.

Comment: Agree with SQL injection part. I just gave an example there. And about $wpdb->posts, I've never known that. Thanks. :)